# Objective C error ';' expected at end of declaration list

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to make a application in XCode and I am trying to make a object in the interface of the viewController class. Every time I do that it just says

> error: `;` expected at end of declaration list

My code:

```
@interface tapViewController () {
    tapScoreController *Score = [[tapScoreController alloc]init];
}
```

Edit: I have been looking through the forums for the same problem and some people said to put it in a different method but I tried that and if I do I can't access the object from a different method

Comment: Have a look at the [FAQ] regarding markdown formatting. The reason your code looked "scrambled" was that you used inline code formatting (backticks), not as a code block (indent with whitespace).

Comment: In addition to Jens Erat's comment above, you can also select the whole code-block and then click on the `{}` button in the button bar to format it.

Comment: No offence, but you might want to pick up a book and learn the basics of Objective-C..

Answer (score 0):

An interface is for declaring instance variables, method definitions, properties, protocols, etc. You added a line of code to your interface. Write your code in the implementation. Here's an example:

```
@interface tapViewController () {
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) Score *tapScoreController;
@end

@implementation tapViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tapScoreController = [[tapScoreController alloc] init];
}

// ...

@end
```

Comment: Thnx but what would I write in my .m file because the .m file, I have already allocated it memory and I have already initialised it

Comment: Remove `tapScoreController *Score = [[tapScoreController alloc]init];` from your .h file. It belongs in your .m file.

Comment: It still shows me the same error and there is a arrow pointing to the '=' in the Object Decleration

Comment: Write it like this: `- (void)thisIsMyNewMethod { tapScoreController *Score = [[tapScoreController alloc]init]; }`

Comment: @bneely The code in the question is not in a .h file. It's an .m file. It is a class extension. Of course it still can't have the assignment but you should update your answer a bit.

Comment: @rmaddy You're right; thanks. I updated my answer and added some sample code.

Comment: Thanks so much, does view did load run when the app is launched

Comment: The UIViewController `viewDidLoad` method will be called when you first create the tapViewController, typically when you call `[[tapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:bundle:]` or `[[tapViewController alloc] init]`. `viewDidLoad` is called before the view appears on the screen. You can review Apple's `UIViewController` documentation for more information.

Comment: I am not sure where you are stuck. Can you describe exactly what is going wrong? Also, you may find it useful to download some sample code from Apple so you can start from working code and go from there.

Comment: It works now but whenever I try to run it, it gives me this error: Apple Mach-O linker error
Linker command failed with exit code

Comment: OK. I think we should wrap up this thread. Can you start a new topic for your linker error issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@interface tapViewController () {
    tapScoreController *Score;
}
```

And in a method

```
-(void) SomeMethod{
     Score = [[tapScoreController alloc]init];
}
```